# OpenCV Perspective Transform (Markerless AR)

Tags: opencv

I’m currently translating a Markerless AR source code written in C++ to C#,
but somehow my outputs are always off the point it should be. Below picture is my output:

[image]

Red circles are supposed to be the correct destination, but instead I got the black circles.
And so I’m wondering if anyone here have any suggestions on what might causing this problem.

I’m not good at describing in words, so I try and describe it in this diagram:

[image]

Video instance:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3MaKHf3AIUU&feature=youtu.be 
In this video:

- Left side image:
  Image shown are generated from Homography Matrix calculated in step 5 and step 6.
- Right side image:
  Image shown are generated from Homography Matrix calculated in step 8.

I uploaded my code onto GitHub:
https://github.com/abc225313/MarkerLessDetector

1. Set marker and Train

   `PatternDetector.cs` → `train(Pattern pattern)`
   `PatternDetector.cs` → `buildPatternFromImage(Mat image, Pattern pattern)`
2. Input image within `main` function
3. Feature Extraction

   `PatternDetector.cs` → `bool extractFeatures (Mat image,ref KeyPoint[] keypoints, ref Mat descriptors)`
4. Feature Matching

   `PatternDetector.cs` → `void getMatches (Mat queryDescriptors, ref DMatch[] matches)`
5. Find Homography

   `PatternDetector.cs` → within `static bool refineMatchesWithHomography`
6. Wrapping

   `PatternDetector.cs` → can be found within `findPattern()`
7. Calculating Homography

   `PatternDetector.cs → calculated in function` findPattern()`
8. PerspectiveTransform

   `PatternDetector.cs` → within `static bool refineMatchesWithHomography`

Comment: your question is about translating `C++` to `C#`  so why the `tag` about `C`?  Please correct the tags